# How does __contains__ work for ndarrays?

Tags: python, numpy

```
>>> x = numpy.array([[1, 2],
...                  [3, 4],
...                  [5, 6]])
>>> [1, 7] in x
True
>>> [1, 2] in x
True
>>> [1, 6] in x
True
>>> [2, 6] in x
True
>>> [3, 6] in x
True
>>> [2, 3] in x
False
>>> [2, 1] in x
False
>>> [1, 2, 3] in x
False
>>> [1, 3, 5] in x
False
```

I have no idea how `__contains__` works for ndarrays. I couldn't find the relevant documentation when I looked for it. How does it work? And is it documented anywhere?

Comment: Look at the source, then.

Comment: @Marcin: The source is buried somewhere in a pile of C that I don't understand the structure to. A big part of it is even autogenerated, and a lot of it is duplicated to handle different dtypes and other differences. I'm not going to dig through all that if I don't have to.

Comment: http://www.mail-archive.com/numpy-discussion@scipy.org/msg31578.html seems to have the answer.

Comment: @AlokSinghal: Further experimentation seems to agree with that post. `[1, object()] in x` and `[object(), 4] in x` report `True`, but `[2, object()] in x` and `[object(), 5] in x` report `False`, and iterating over `itertools.product(xrange(1, 7), repeat=2)` and checking containment for all pairs gives the expected results. I was really hoping for something better than a mailing list archive, but if that's all there is, I'll take it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found the source for `ndarray.__contains__`, in [`numpy/core/src/multiarray/sequence.c`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.18.1/numpy/core/src/multiarray/sequence.c#L28). As a comment in the source states,

```
thing in x
```

is equivalent to

```
(x == thing).any()
```

for an ndarray `x`, regardless of the dimensions of `x` and `thing`. This only makes sense when `thing` is a scalar; the results of broadcasting when `thing` isn't a scalar cause the weird results I observed, as well as oddities like `array([1, 2, 3]) in array(1)` that I didn't think to try. The exact source is

```c
static int
array_contains(PyArrayObject *self, PyObject *el)
{
    /* equivalent to (self == el).any() */

    int ret;
    PyObject *res, *any;

    res = PyArray_EnsureAnyArray(PyObject_RichCompare((PyObject *)self,
                                                      el, Py_EQ));
    if (res == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }
    any = PyArray_Any((PyArrayObject *)res, NPY_MAXDIMS, NULL);
    Py_DECREF(res);
    ret = PyObject_IsTrue(any);
    Py_DECREF(any);
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Seems like `numpy`'s `__contains__` is doing something like this for a 2-d case:

```
def __contains__(self, item):
    for row in self:
        if any(item_value == row_value for item_value, row_value in zip(item, row)):
            return True
    return False
```

`[1,7]` works because the `0`th element of the first row matches the `0`th element of `[1,7]`.  Same with `[1,2]` etc.  With `[2,6]`, the 6 matches the 6 in the last row.  With `[2,3]`, none of the elements match a row at the same index. `[1, 2, 3]` is trivial since the shapes don't match.

See [this](http://www.mail-archive.com/numpy-discussion@scipy.org/msg31578.html) for more, and also [this ticket](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/3016).

Comment: It seems to me that `all` would be more practically useful than `any`, I wonder why `numpy` developers chose this implementation of `__contains__`.

Comment: @Akavall Seems to be for compatibility with Numeric.  In Numeric, an array's boolean value was assumed to be `True` if it contained at least one non-zero element.  Numpy raises exceptions when one tries to  use an array as a boolean, saying that one should use `any()` or `all()`.

In this case though, `__contains__()` API is forcing Numpy to interpret an array in a boolean context, and for this, they decided to go with what Numeric did.

But I agree, it's really confusing and I don't know if *anyone* depends on this behavior of `__contains__()`.

Answer (score -1):

## how to check is a 1 dimensional `np.ndarray` is equivalent to a row in a 2 dimensional `np.ndarray`

[As pointed out already](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30690604/7128154),

`[1, 2] in x`
is equivalent to
`([1, 2] == x).any()`.

`[1,2,3] in x` nowadays throws a `DeprecationWarning`, as it is 3 elements long, while `x.shape[1]` is only 2.

If you just want to find out if an `np.ndarray` is just **contained (in the human interpreted way)** in an other `np.ndarray`, use this

```
>>> x = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])
>>> np.any([np.array_equal([1, 7], el) for el in list(x)])
False
>>> np.any([np.array_equal([1, 2], el) for el in list(x)])
True
```