# Numpy array __contains__ check

Tags: python, numpy

I got an array of arrays:

```
temp = np.empty(5, dtype=np.ndarray) 
temp[0] = np.array([0,1])
```

I want to check if `np.array([0,1]) in temp`, which in the above example clearly is but the code returns false. I also tried `temp.__contains__(np.array([0,1]))` but also returns false. Why is this? Shouldn't it return true?

EDIT:

So `__contain__` wont work. Is there any other way of checking?

Comment: [Don't try to use `__contains__` in NumPy. It does crazy, useless shit.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18320624/how-does-contains-work-for-ndarrays)

Comment: so as of now the best solution is to iterate through the whole array to check each time?

Comment: numpy arrays with `dtype=object` are not very well developed.  Basic things like indexing work.  But binary operations are hit and miss.

Answer (score 2):

One thing you need to understand, in python in general, is that, semantically, `__contains__` is based on `__eq__`, i.e. it looks for an element which satisfies the `==` predicate. (Of course one can override the `__contains__` operator to do other things, but that's a different story).

Now, with numpy arrays, the `__eq__` does not return `bool` at all. Every person using numpy encountered this error at some point:

```
if temp == temp2:
   print 'ok'
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Which means, given the conflicting semantics of the `__contains__` and `ndarray.__eq__`, it's not surprising this operation does not do what you want.

With the code you posted, there is no clear advantage to setting `temp` to be a `np.array` over a `list`. In either case, you can "simulate" the behavior of `__contains__` with something like:

```
temp2 = np.array([0,1])
any( (a == temp2).all() for a in temp if a is not None )
```

If you explain why you choose to use an hetrogeneous `np.array` in the first place, I might come up with a more detailed solution.

And, of course, this answer would not be complete without @user2357112's link to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18320624/how-does-contains-work-for-ndarrays).