# Numpy array exclude some elements

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
training_images = np.array([i for i in images if i not in validation_images])
```

The above is wrong (as noted in a comment below). What's a correct and faster way of doing this?

My validation_images is just

```
 validation_images = images[::6]
```

and the shape of images is (60000, 784).
This is a numpy array.

The current method is not acceptable because it is too slow.

Comment: Note: [`in` for arrays makes no sense](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18320624/how-does-contains-work-for-ndarrays), so your current code probably isn't doing what you want anyway. Also, how should this be affected by duplicates? Do you just want to drop every row whose index is a multiple of 6?

Comment: I didn't know that. But anyway, I want to do what I intended to do there. Yeah I don't care about duplicates, I just want to drop one row every 6 rows for my validation set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm always using [boolean masks](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays) for such things, you could consider:

```
# Mask every sixth row
mask = (np.arange(images.shape[0]) % 6) != 0

# Only use the not masked images
training_images = images[mask]
```

The validation set would then be every masked element:

```
validation_images = images[~mask]
```

---

Mathematical operations on numpy arrays work element wise, so taking the [modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) (`%`) will be executed on each element and returns another array with the same shape. The `!= 0` works also element-wise and compares if the modulo is not zero. So the mask is just an array containing `False` where the value is not an `int * 6` and `True` where it is.

Comment: np.arange(images.shape[0]) gives you an array, why are you able to do (THIS %6) != 0? What are you doing there and why does it work? Can you explain it?

Comment: I've edited a small text at the end explaining the context of the operations.

Answer (score 0):

```
Z = np.linspace(0,1,12)[1:-1] 

#Create a vector of size 10 with values ranging from 0 to 1, both excluded

print(Z)
```