# Comparing numpy arrays with individual values

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy-array "target_tokes" with many values. I try to receive a numpy_array of the same shape, with 1. at a position where in the target_tokens array I had a specific value (i.e. a nine or a two).

This works (for the nine):

```
i_factor        = (target_tokens == 9).astype(np.float32)
```

Result:

```
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]...
```

This does not work:

```
group           = [2, 9]
i_factor        = (target_tokens in group).astype(np.float32)
```

Result is:

```
i_factor        = (target_tokens in group).astype(np.float32) 
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Why is that and how can I still achieve my result without having big loops (the group is bigger in reality than just two values).

Thx

Comment: Not sure if I got it, how about : `np.asarray(target_tokens)[:,None] == range(9)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like `and` and `or`, `in` isn't allowed to broadcast. The Python language requires that `in` always returns a boolean. Also, only the right-hand operand can define what `in` means, and you used a list, not an array. You're getting the `in` behavior of Python lists.

NumPy's `in` operator is [pretty weird](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18320624/how-does-contains-work-for-ndarrays) and not useful for you. `in` for lists makes more sense, but still isn't what you need. You need [`numpy.isin`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html), which behaves like an `in` test broadcasted across its left operand (but not its right):

```
numpy.isin(target_tokens, group).astype(np.float32)
```

Answer (score 2):

#### You can use a [`bitwise operator`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators)

Let's first simplify what you are trying to achieve with a more basic `array`:

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 7, 3, 9, 6])
```

and the `numbers` you want to check against:

```
g = [2, 9]
```

To get an `array` of `1s` and `0s` representing whether or not each `element` is equal to either of the `elements` in `g`, we can use the `bitwise` `or` which is `'|'`:

```
((a == g[0]) | (a == g[1])).astype(np.float32)
```

which gives:

```
array([ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.], dtype=float32)
```

---

This will also work for higher `dimensional` `arrays`.

Such as with:

```
a = np.array([[1, 5, 7], [9, 3, 2], [5, 8, 9]])
```

which (with the same `g`) will give:

```
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.]], dtype=float32)
```

---

*Note that you can also achieve the same thing with [`np.bitwise_or()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.bitwise_or.html) which is what you would need to use if you wanted the `g` `list` to be of any size.*

---

If you wanted to allow `g` to be any size, you could no longer use the `bitwise` `or` `'|'` operand unless you wrote a `for-loop` to do it in. So to escape a `for-loop`, we could use `np.bitwise_or.reduce` on the `arrays`.

So with the original `array`:

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 7, 3, 9, 6])
```

but now with a longer `g`:

```
g = [1, 7, 9, 4]
```

we can use the `np.bitwise_or.reduce`:

```
np.bitwise_or.reduce([a == e for e in g]).astype(np.float32)
```

which gives:

```
array([ 1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: Learned a lot and like it, even though the simpler solution np.isin() is what I implemented here. Still thx1

Answer (score 2):

A couple of options besides the bitwise-OR described in @JoeIddon's solution.

One solution is based on @Divakar's comment:

```
group = [1, 9]
a = np.array([1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 9, 9, 2])
(np.asarray(group)[:,None] == a).sum(axis=0)
```

or, if you need `np.float32` type:

```
(np.asarray(group)[:,None] == a).sum(axis=0, dtype=np.float32)
```

Another one is to use list comprehension, equality testing for each test value in the group, and add solutions:

```
group = [1, 9]
a = np.array([1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 9, 9, 2])
np.sum(a == g for g in group)
```

or, if you need `np.float32` type:

```
np.sum((a == g for g in group), dtype=np.float32)
```

In both cases the answer will be:

```
array([1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]) # or float32
```

Comment: My sol uses `bitwise-or`! Nice use of `sum` though +1