# What is the meaning of the "in" operator between numpy arrays?

Tags: python, numpy

I noticed that `in` can be used between numpy arrays. However its meaning can be a bit counter-intuitive.

```
import numpy as np
np.array([0]) in np.array([1, 2])
# False
np.array([0]) in np.array([0, 1])
# True
np.array([0, 1]) in np.array([0])
# True -- somewhat surprisingly
```

So it seems that it behaves like `np.any(np.isin(·, ·))` rather than the somewhat more intuitive `np.all(np.isin(·, ·))`.

1. Is this really the case?
2. What is the rationale behind this choice?

Comment: you should as numpy's authors. Maybe they use `any` because it was more useful or more intuitive for authors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does \_\_contains\_\_ work for ndarrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18320624/how-does-contains-work-for-ndarrays)

Comment: @Joanna thanks, that confirms my observation, but I would still like to hear about the reasons (or lack thereof) behind this choice.

Answer (score 0):

As the "in" operator behaviour is defined by the implementation of the contains method of np.array class, you should check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/30690604/7533781 - it is very well explained.

Following this definition also [0, 1] in np.array([0]) evaluates to True - you can try it yourself.