# find and count the elements of one list in another list don't work when import .csv file

Tags: python, pandas, python-import

I want to check if elements of list1 are in list2. if so, I want to add up the elements.

It works without an extern .csv file:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
list2 = [1,2,3]

c = sum(el in list1 for el in list2)
print(c)
```

But when I import a .csv file, the expected answer is incorrect.

**Expected answer:** 6

```
import pandas as pd 
list1 = pd.read_csv(r"list1.csv")
list2 = pd.read_csv(r"list2.csv")

cs = sum(el in list1 for el in list2)
print(cs)
```

[list 1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KeqO5RuoHrdrq3_WB9WLVUFVRA-ntqOd/view?usp=sharing)
[list 2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uDP92v4Ds7rM2C5jTKLxMEq2M4WD5l9c/view?usp=sharing)

I think it has something to do with the way I import the files? Or do I need to convert the objects? Your help is welcome :)

Comment: "the expected answer is incorrect" - so what answer do you get instead of the correct one?

Comment: Also, you say you "want to check if elements of list1 are in list2", but `el in list1` checks if elements of `list2` are in `list1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `list1` is not really a list but a `DataFrame`.

`in` in `numpy` is not working like it works on `list` as you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58266629/3700626).

So if you want to stick with your `list` working code you should `.tolist()` your `DataFrame`.

or use the `isin` as suggested in the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

When you read csv with pandas, you get a dataframe, whereas you want to work with series. Even in this case, your dataframes have only one column, you still need to specify the column:

```
c = list1['A'].isin(list2['A']).sum()
```

In your case, you can print

```
print([el for el in list 2])
```

to see what you are looping over.

Answer (score 0):

You only have to convert list1 and list2 into numpy arrays and it works just fine. Try

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
list1 = np.array(pd.read_csv(r"list1.csv"))
list2 = np.array(pd.read_csv(r"list2.csv"))

cs = sum(el in list1 for el in list2)
print(cs)
```