# How does 'in' work for python list and numpy array?

Tags: python, list, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have something similar to the following code:

```py
list1 = [(13,120), (25, 254), (25, 125), (189, 11), ....] 
list2 = [ list(el) for el in list1]
arr = np.array(list2)
```

Let's say `list1` has a length of 100 and hence, `arr` has a shape (100, 2)

```py
tuple_list = some tuple list where tuple size is 2 i.e [(5, 56), (254, 23), (22, 22), ...]
count_list = 0
count_arr = 0
for tup in tuple_list:
    if tup in list1:
        count_list += 1
    if list(tup) in arr:
        count_arr += 1
```

I expected `count_list` and `count_arr` to be equal but they are showing different values. So my question is how does `in` work for `list` and `ndarray`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18320624/how-does-contains-work-for-ndarrays

Comment: The array does not contain tuples; the tuples were used to initialize *rows*, not *elements*, of the array.

Comment: Show the different results; don't just say they are different!

Comment: Yes, `in` can be quite different when applied an `ndarray`; as a general idea it isn't a good idea to try it.  `arr` does not contain lists or tuples, even when its shape is (100,2).  `in`, depending on the objects, may use equality.   Look at `[5,56]==arr`.  The result is (100,2), not (100,)