# Python "in" keyword-function does not work properly on numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

Why does this piece of code return `True` when it clearly can be seen that the element `[1, 1]` is not present in the first array and what am I supposed to change in order to make it return `False`?

```
aux = np.asarray([[0, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3]])
np.asarray([1, 1]) in aux
```

> True

Comment: Why not use [isin()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html?highlight=isin#numpy.isin)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18320624/how-does-contains-work-for-ndarrays

Comment: @RandomDavis: Doesn't work. That broadcasts over the left operand. It doesn't mean "is this array in this other array"; it means "for each element of this array, is that element in this other array".

Comment: In a deleted comment you say the actual arrays are float.  `==` tests don't work reliably on  floats.  Giving an `int` example will probably produce useless answers.

Comment: You are assuming that `in` applied to arrays should behave the same as  with lists.  Use lists if that's what you want.  Otherwise, accept the fact that `numpy` arrays are multidimensional, and implement their own form of `in`.  Generally though, we don't use `in` with arrays.  There are better tools that give more control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking for equality for the two arrays broadcasts the 1d array so the `==` operator checks if the corresponding indices are equal.

```py
>>> np.array([1, 1]) == aux
array([[False,  True],
       [ True, False],
       [ True, False]])
```

Since none of the inner arrays are all `True`, no array in `aux` is completely equal to the other array. We can check for this using

```py
np.any(np.all(np.array([1, 1]) == aux, axis=1))
```

Comment: And it is quite performant as well. Testing an array with 1e6 lines takes about 0.015 s in my machine (`timeit.timeit('np.any(np.all(a == b, axis=1))', setup='import numpy as np; a=np.random.rand(1000000, 2); b=np.asarray([-1,1])', number=10)/10`)

Answer (score -1):

You can think of the `in` operator looping through an iterable and comparing each item for equality with what's being matched. I think what happens here can be demonstrated with the comparison to the first vector in the matrix/list:

```
>>> np.array([1, 1]) == np.array([0,1])
array([False,  True])
```

and `bool([False, True])` in Python == `True` so the `in` operator immediately returns.