# Why is true being printed even though the numpy array [1,5] is not in y?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
import numpy as np

y=np.array([[0, 0]]*100)
y[0]=np.array([2,1])
y[1]=np.array([1,2])

print(np.array([1, 5]) in y)
```

Even though [1,5] is not in y, True is being printed. The correct output should be False.

I am dumbfounded. Why is this happening?

Comment: `[1, 5] in y` is equivalent to `([1, 5] == y).any()`

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70279922/python-in-keyword-function-does-not-work-properly-on-numpy-arrays and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18320624/how-does-contains-work-for-ndarrays

Comment: Generally functions (or operators) that don't take an `axis`, or with default `axis=None`, operate on a flattened array.  So it's just checking if there's a `1` somewhere in `y`, not that there's `[1,5]` array among the rows of `y`.

Comment: `(np.array([1,5])==y).all(axis=1).any()` is more likely the test you want.  Even with that you need to understand `broadcasting`, how a (2,) array can be compared to a (n,2).  And of course the meaning  of the `axis=1` parameter.